# Sum and Count from joinee and count from joiner table group by single column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to build a query to be displayed on a table for a web app. The goal is to get a table that looks like this.

```
source          | totalBytes | totalPackets | totalFlows |
----------------------------------------------------------
192.168.1.1     | 53341      | 1002         | 100        |
192.168.1.2     | 4222333    | 2535         | 5          |
192.168.1.3     | 244451     | 110          | 25         |
```

I can get to this query very easily but once I want to try to get packet count I have problems integrating the total amount of packets for each flow in the group by.

```
SELECT 
  source, 
  SUM("totalPacketLength") AS totalBytes, 
  COUNT(flows.id) totalFlows
FROM pcaps.flow flows 
WHERE flows.pcap_id = 15 
GROUP BY source
ORDER BY sum DESC
```

RESULT:

```
source          | totalBytes | totalFlows |
-------------------------------------------
192.168.1.1     | 53341      | 100        |
192.168.1.2     | 4222333    | 5          |
192.168.1.3     | 244451     | 25         |
```

I have also tried this query

```
SELECT 
    source, 
    SUM("totalPacketLength") AS totalBytes, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT packets.id) totalPackets,
    COUNT(DISTINCT flows.id) totalFlows
FROM pcaps.flow flows 
    LEFT JOIN pcaps.packet packets 
        ON packets.flow = flows.id AND packets.pcap = flows.pcap_id
WHERE flows.pcap_id = 15 
GROUP BY source
ORDER BY sum DESC
```

This produces the wrong `totalBytes` (even if I use `DISTINCT`).

Comment: You need to do join on the two queries. Also you did not mention what is the huge problem you are getting, just said you had huge problem.

Comment: Your query seems to match the expectation of generating totalBytes and totalFlows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to aggregate before joining.  I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT f.source, 
       SUM("totalPacketLength") AS totalBytes, 
       COUNT(f.id) totalFlows,
       SUM(p.num_packets)
FROM pcaps.flow f LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT p.flow, p.pcap_id, COUNT(*) as num_packets
      FROM pcaps.packet  p
      GROUP BY p.flow, p.pcap_id
     ) p
     ON packets.flow = flows.id AND packets.pcap = flows.pcap_id
WHERE f.pcap_id = 15 
GROUP BY f.source
ORDER BY sum DESC
```